# Unique top result in access database

Tags: ms-access

I'm building a Access Database query, I am currently having Access 2013. I have table with duplicate records. In one query I sorted the table in a way I want to see the top unique values. Now, I want to remove duplicates and want to have just first unique record from that sorted table.i tried multiple ways to do it but hard luck. Here is an example.

I have a table with Control ID, the assessments date, Effectiveness, Evaluation date and Latest assessment

```
Control Id   Effectiveness  Evaluation Date  Latest Assessment
50373993      Effective      7/30/2019        X
50373993      Effective      6/24/2019
50373993      Effective      5/17/2018
50373993      Effective      7/18/2019
50373993      Effective      6/21/2019
```

I made one query where I sorted this table first on Evaluation date and then by Latest Assessment. Now I want a unique table for Control Id where it shows first record after sorting. See below

```
Control Id   Effectiveness  Evaluation Date  Latest Assessment
50373993      Effective      7/30/2019        X
```

Could you please help me here?

Comment: Does anyone has solution for this?

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT TOP 1 table.* FROM table ORDER BY ...;`? Can set TOP by using Property Sheet window of query in Design View.